# Добавление и отображение полей в DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте! У меня есть модель вида:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(name="name", max_length=128)
   address = models.CharField(name="address", max_length=128)
   code = models.CharField(name="code", max_length=10)
   created_time = models.TimeField(name="created_time")
```

Есть сериализатор:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('address',)
```

есть viewSet для создания записей указанных моделей:

```
class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    queryset = MyModel.objects
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы при отправке POST запроса содержащий поле address создавалось запись в БД. Но поля name, code, created_time - задавались на моей стороне в зависимости от того какое содержимое у address. При этом в ответе клиенту должно приходить поле code, которое сгенирировал я. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать? Если можно с примерами кода.

P.S.
С DRF не работал, представляю крайне слабо. Если я правильно понимаю логику работы, то после routes запрос попадает на MyViewSet, который передает их MySerializer. MySerializer - занимается тем, что переводит данные из JSON в объекты DRF. То есть логика создания всех моих полей будет на стороне MyViewSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете перегрузить метод `create` у сериалайзера, так же в `fields` можно оставить все поля которые нужны для вывода и сделать их `read_only`.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('address', 'name', 'code', 'created_time')
        read_only_fields = ('name', 'code', 'created_time')

    def create(self, validated_data): 
        # validated_data будет представлять собой словарь с полем 'address'
        address = validated_data.get('address')
        validated_data.update(
            {
                'name': # получаете значение name по address,
                'code': # получаете код по address
                # и т.п.
            }
        )
        # передаем дополненый словарь с вычисленными данным в родительский create
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

p.s. `class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin):` миксины всегда нужна ставить слева в цепочки наследования, т.к. обычно они нужны для перегрузки методов классов, которые стоят дальше в цепочке.

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, как можно проверить есть ли в БД запись таким же address? Вариант, когда в модели поле помечается как unique=True не подходит. Нужно именно найти запись с таким же address

Comment: `MyModel.objects.filter(address='some_address').count()`